# How to establish a secure connection with MySQL/PHP

Tags: mysql, security

I'm currently doing a Capstone project and I need to establish a secure connection between PHP and MySQL. Is it there some kind of method ?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "secure", what you mean by "connection" and what you mean by "between".  Do you mean to create an encrypted connection between a web server running PHP and a database server running MySQL?

Comment: @ChrisBrowne, yeah create an encrypted connection between a web server running PHP and the database running mysql

Comment: my naive solution would be to set up an SSH tunnel as I'm not aware of MySQL supporting encrypted connections natively, but I'm probably not the right person to ask.  Still, if it helps - an SSH tunnel would provide an encrypted channel for your MySQL data.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SSL to connect to MySQl](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-using-ssl.html).   This specifics of this varies based on your platform.